# C - producer/consumer deadlock issue

Tags: c, deadlock, semaphore, producer-consumer

I'm trying to work with producer/consumer threads in a bounded buffer. The buffer length is 5. I have 1 mutex and 2 semaphores, empty which starts out at the size of the buffer, and full, which starts out at 0.

When I run my code without sleep() at the end, it continually produces until the buffer is completely fully, the consumes until it's empty, so the output looks like this:

```
Placed 1 in the buffer at position 0.
Placed 2 in the buffer at position 1.
Placed 3 in the buffer at position 2.
Placed 4 in the buffer at position 3.
Placed 5 in the buffer at position 4.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 0.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 1.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 2.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 3.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 4.
```

However, when i run with sleep() at the end, it prints out:

```
Placed 1 in the buffer at position 0.
The buffer now contains 0 at position 0.
```

Then it appears to lock up, but I'm not really sure why it behaves the way it does regardless of whether or not sleep is there. Any suggestions? My main method essentially just makes some declarations then creates 1 thread to produce and 1 to consume, those methods are below.

```
void *producer()
{
        int k = 0; //producer index
        while (1)
        {
                sem_wait(&empty);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                buffer[k] = k+1;
                sem_post(&full);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                printf("Placed %d in the buffer at position %d.\n", buffer[k], k);
                k = (k + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
                sleep(rand() * 10);
        }
}

void *consumer()
{
        int j = 0;   //consumer index
        while(1)
        {
                sem_wait(&full);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                buffer[j] = 0;
                sem_post(&empty);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                printf("The buffer now contains %d at position %d.\n", buffer[j], j);
                j = (j + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
                sleep(rand() * 10);

        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to throw your code away and rewrite the task in pseudocode. Or you may rewrite it in C again, that usually helps me to find such hard bugs.

Comment: One (unrelated) problem I can see, the consumer index `j` should be shared amongst consumers.  It doesn't help if it's local to each thread.  Make `j` global.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually planning on doing that for when I implement multiple threads, but for now I only have 1 producer and 1 consumer each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `sleep()` is the number of seconds to sleep for.  `rand()` returns an integer between 0 and `RAND_MAX` (typically 32767 or 2<sup>31</sup>-1), and when you multiply that by 10, you're sleeping for an absurdly large amount of time.  You're not deadlocking, just sleeping for a very long time.

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason I thought rand() was in between 0 and 1. Thanks, I'll try adjusting it.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Do you have any idea why when I don't include sleep it always produces and consumes in blocks instead of every other?

Comment: @john If you don't force anything, you typically get the most efficient result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is the reason for your deadlock, but you have to be careful with `sem_t` functions they are subject to interrupts, in particular due to IO and things like that.

Never ignore returns from system functions. Here, you'd have to check the return and then `errno` for `EINTR`.

Then, I don't know if you are forced to use `sem_t`, but I think more natural here would be to use a `pthread_cond_t`. You have a mutex anyhow, so this would fit more easily. `pthread_cond_t` as `pthread_mutex_t` functions will never be interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

`Do you have any idea why when I don't include sleep it always produces and consumes in blocks instead of every other?`

Thats probably because the ~30 ms time slice each thread is given is more than enough to have the producer produce everything, before a context switch had a chance to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both your threads have the same priority? And is this on a machine with multiple cores, or just one? Just signaling a semaphore will not preempt your current thread, so it is to be expected for the current thread to carry on until its slice expires.

Also, I would definitely unlock the mutex before signaling the mutex.

Comment: The machine I'm on is dual core. If the consumer thread is running at the same time, constantly checking for the condition that it can start consuming, and the producer thread signals a semaphore after 1 production, shouldn't the consumer start running after the producer has run once?

Comment: It should. Btw, what is the mutex for? Since you signal the semaphore after you're done writing (like you should), you're guaranteed to never write to the same address that the consumer thread is reading from.

Comment: Well, a lot of code I looked at used it and for this lab I thought I was supposed to treat accessing the buffer as a critical section. If I had multiple consumers and producers wouldn't I need the mutex anyway?

Comment: A mutex needs to have a reason. You need to have a shared resource. In this particular example, I don't see a shared resource - the producer will only ever write to memory that the consumer will only ever access AFTER the producer has signaled the semaphore. Of course, if there's more to your code than what you posted, you may need a mutex. In any case, did you try taking the mutex out?